# Inserting a div after the first <p> inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to insert a dynamic `div` after the second image inside a master `div` and works great. I tried to modified it so I can insert another `div` after the second `<p>` but it's not working.. any ideas?

My code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".post_text").find("img:eq(1)").after("<div id='1' style='width:643px; height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#000;'><div class='gad' style='width: 300px; height:250px; float: left; margin-left: 171px;'></div></div>");
});
```

modified:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".post_text").find("p:eq(1)").after("<div id='1' style='width:643px; height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#000;'><div class='gad' style='width: 300px; height:250px; float: left; margin-left: 171px;'></div></div>");
});
```

my HTML

```
<div class="post_text">
  <p>blah blah blah</p>
  <p>second p blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/BFVLe/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D63sQ/1/ - seems fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".post_text" ).append( "<div id='1' etc..." );
```

will put it at the end, inside the div, after the last p.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `find("p:eq(1)")`, you use an index of 1. Since it is 0 based and append will add it after the element you should use an index of 0.

`$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".post_text").find("p:eq(0)").after("");
});`

This will add it after the first (0) p-element. Instead of adding it after the second (1).